# Migrations canceled: undefined method `int'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `rake db:migrate`, show the following error:

```
-- create_table(:posts)<br>
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:`<br>
undefined method 'int' for #
<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x0055c088b9f520>
Did you mean?  in?
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Please post the migration file

Comment: while creating `posts` table, you've possibly written something  like `foo:int`. that should be `foo:integer`. fix it in your migration file, it will work -))

Comment: The posts migration is what is causing the error. The comment above mine is likely your solution.

Comment: Thanks guys. The solution is how @marmeladze wrote. I just change the migrate file in db/migrate from `int` to `integer`. Like this: `t.integer: age`.
Tanks @marmeladze.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just change the migrate file in db/migrate from `int` to `integer`. Like this: **`t.integer: age`**

Comment: Your answer solved my error. I would be curious to know why this error occurred. I ran `rails g model Item month:string year:int name:string price:float description:text path:string type:string` and immediately afterwards ran `rake db:migrate` - it seems odd that rails would have what could almost be called a typo.. (i.e. "Int" where it should say "Integer")

Answer (score 1):

A reason this could happen is if you accidentally got a column name and a data type around the wrong way during `rails generate model ...`.

For example, if you accidentally ran `rails g model calculations references:appointment` (instead of `rails g model calculations appointment:references`), then you'd have:

```rb
t.appointment :references
```

but it should be

```rb
t.references :appointment
```

The same mistake could happen with not just `references`, but any other data type too (e.g. `integer`, `string` and so on).